# Using Eigen BICGSTAB in Parallel to solve the sparse matrix

Tags: c++, openmp, sparse-matrix, eigen, linear-equation

I am trying to solve a linear system of equations of the form `Ax=b` with the Eigen BICGSTAB in parallel.

```
initParallel();
int n=4;
omp_set_num_threads(n);
setNbThreads(n);

BiCGSTAB  <SparseMatrix<double>> solver;
solver.compute(A);
x = solver.solve(b);
```

I also enable the OpenMP in the visual studio. but I can't see any increase in CPU usage when I increase the number of thread. As a results I cannot see any enhancement in its performance.

However, When I used LeastSquaresConjugateGradient as a solver, the CPU usage increases when I increase the number of threads, that means I could successfully parallel it, but as I said it does not work for BiCGSTAB.

```
initParallel();
int n=4;
omp_set_num_threads(n);
setNbThreads(n);

LeastSquaresConjugateGradient <SparseMatrix<double>> solver;
solver.compute(A);
x = solver.solve(b);
```

anyone can advise me why it is not paralleled for BiCGSTAB and how can do that?

Comment: Eigen documentation says that BiCGSTAB can make use of multi-threading with a [row-major sparse matrix format](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html). Is this your case? By default, `SparseMatrix<double>` resovles in the [column-major format](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrix.html).

Comment: solved now,
I defined the spars matrix as row major as:

SparseMatrix<double,RowMajor> A(n, n);

but to make it parallel, we have to again call it as row major in BiCGSTAB as :

BiCGSTAB  <SparseMatrix<double,RowMajor>> solver;

Comment: Great! Please take some time to write your own answer (as an answer, not as a comment) and mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

to parallel the Eigen BICGSTAB:

```
int n=4;
omp_set_num_threads(n);
setNbThreads(n);

BiCGSTAB  <SparseMatrix<double>,RowMajor> solver;
solver.compute(A);
x = solver.solve(b);
```