# paralleling BiCGSTAB using RowMajor sparse matrix still run in siquential

Tags: parallel-processing, eigen

I am using [BiCGSTAB](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1BiCGSTAB.html) to solve a sparse system of equations. I have used [MPFR](https://www.mpfr.org/)  for multiprecision and the following code, but the code is running sequentially.
I followed the  [Make Eigen run in parallel](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html).

```cpp
using MatrixXmp = Eigen::Matrix<mpfr::mpreal, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>;
using VectorXmp = Eigen::Matrix<mpfr::mpreal, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>;
...

omp_set_num_threads(num_threads);
Eigen::setNbThreads(num_threads);
mpfr::mpreal::set_default_prec(128);

Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<mpfr::mpreal, Eigen::RowMajor>> solver;
solver.setTolerance(tol);
solver.setMaxIterations(maxiter);
solver.compute(A);
xx = solver.solve(b);
```

**compile:**

```sh
g++ -o solver main.cpp -lmpfr -lgmp -fopenmp
```

I check `top` for cpu usage. My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.
I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58875483/using-eigen-bicgstab-in-parallel-to-solve-the-sparse-matrix) which is almost the same but I still have the sequential running issue.

**Edit:** I fill matrix `A` like this:

```cpp
Eigen::SparseMatrix<mpfr::mpreal, Eigen::RowMajor> A(num_rows, num_rows);
A.reserve(Eigen::RowVectorXi::Constant(num_elements, 3));

for (int i = 0; i < num_elements; i++)
{
    A.insert(rows[i], cols[i]) = data[i];
}
A.makeCompressed();
```

Comment: Maybe the matrix should be bigger. Alternatively it my be because of the specialized type. Did you tried with double precision? That being said, you need to enable optimizations for your code to be fast using `-O3`.

Comment: I have tried everything, It would be better if a working example be available. Does it even work?

Comment: At the time of this reply, the same problem still exists.